# How can I refer to a new page in Windows Store universal app (Visual C++) In Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to Windows app development. I created a project in visual studio 2015 under visual c++ universal store app. I added a new page from

```
project > add new item > xaml > basic page
```

I want to refer to the new page when I click a button in the main page.

The new page name is **BasicPage**

I added

```
#include "BasicPage.xaml.h"
```

and

```
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
```

to the **MainPage.xaml.cpp** file, added a button to **MainPage** and added this code in the button's click event:

```
    void Apptest_0_3::MainPage::button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (this->Frame != nullptr)
    {
        this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(BasicPage::typeid));
    }

}
```

[image]
but I get the following error when I click the button

[image]

**How Can I fix this error?**